# Android get properties for polygon from GeoJson

Tags: android, dictionary, properties, polygon, geojson

Im adding GeoJsonLayer to Google map on my application. This json contains coordinates for polygon and properties for each polygon. What I need is to get those properties when polygon is clicked. This is the code Im using to achieve that.

```
 GeoJsonLayer jsonLayer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, geoJSON);
 jsonLayer.addLayerToMap();

    jsonLayer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeatureClick(final com.google.maps.android.data.Feature feature) {
                mMap.setOnPolygonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {

                        for (Object s : feature.getProperties()) {
                            Log.d("getProperties", "getProperties = " + s.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The problem is that it returns all properties. I want it to return properties only for the polygon I clicked.

Also its possible to draw polygons with user input. When I click on those polygons it triggers `onPolygonClick()` inside `jsonLayer.setOnFeatureClickListener()`. How to check if clicked polygon is from jsonLayer?